# Django DataError at /admin/posts/post/add/ integer out of range

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, uuid

I'm getting an integer out of range error when I create a new post in Django Admin. This is DRF project with a Post model that uses a UUIDField as id which is the primary key. It seems like the ID field is causing the problem but I don't understand how the UUIDField can be out of bounds. None of the remaining fields like Title or URL could be out of range.

When I go to create a new post in the Admin dashboard, I get this error message after I click the Save button:

```
DataError at /admin/posts/post/add/
integer out of range
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/posts/post/add/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: DataError
Exception Value:    
integer out of range
Exception Location: /Users/username/Desktop/Workspace/project-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 86
Python Executable:  /Users/username/Desktop/Workspace/project-api/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

Here's the Model:

```
class UUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class TimeStampedUUIDModel(UUIDModel):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Post(TimeStampedUUIDModel):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    title = models.CharField(
        _("Title"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(
        _("Description"), max_length=1500, blank=False, null=False)
    url = models.URLField(_("URL"), unique=True,
                          max_length=155, blank=False, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(
        _("Country"), max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)

    post_image = VersatileImageField(
        "Post image",
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        upload_to=post_image_directory,
        ppoi_field="post_image_ppoi"
    )
    post_image_ppoi = PPOIField()

    STATUS_DRAFT = "D"
    STATUS_PUBLISHED = "P"
    STATUSES = (
        (STATUS_DRAFT, "Draft"),
        (STATUS_PUBLISHED, "Published"),
    )
    status = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, choices=STATUSES,
                              default=STATUS_DRAFT, max_length=2)
... ...
```

I've looked at various answers but can't find an answer to the integer out of range issue. The Trace shows the following message:

```
2020-08-18 10:03:44,953:[ERROR]:logger=django.request:request_id=a6d4549d7bfb42f2b780473bcc19ebdf message='Internal Server Error: /admin/posts/post/add/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Workspace/project-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 559, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Workspace/project-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
taggit.models.TaggedItem.DoesNotExist: TaggedItem matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Workspace/project-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: integer out of range


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trace shows that the issue is related to the taggit library. I don't see a tag field on your post model but if you have one, try removing it, make migrations and try again.